# Autocomplete jQuery UI plugin with JSP and Servlets not working

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, autocomplete

I'm trying to use jQuery UI autocomplete widget in my Java Webb App.

As it is right now I have the following code:

**View (buscarFoto.jsp)**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Escull usuari</h3>
    <input type="text" id="usuari" name="usuari"/>

    <script>
        $("#usuari").autocomplete({
            source: "Controller?action=llistaUsuaris"
        });
    </script>   
</body>
```

**Controller (Controller.java (servlet))** (DoPost and DoGet are overwritten, Controller.java works just fine as Servlet in any other part of the WebApp)

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {

        GestioDB_Postgres db = new GestioDB_Postgres();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String op = request.getParameter("action");

        if (op.equals("llistaUsuaris")) {
            String query = request.getParameter("term");
            List<String> usuaris = db.llistaUsuaris(query);
            Iterator<String> iterator = usuaris.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String usuari = (String) iterator.next();
                out.println(usuari);
            }

        }
```

The call to the database in line 3 of the Controller works just fine (I've tested it), and the controller itself works fine too (it prints the appropriate "usuaris" when I run it in NetBeans), the .jsp page sends the request as "term", but the autocomplete function simply doesn't do anything.

I read in another question that someone suggested using JSON but I'd rather not use it if it can be avoided. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console.

Comment: No, no errors. I only get this:    [12:08:05.071] GET url*/Controller?action=llistaUsuaris&term=e [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 125ms]   *(I've hid the actual url)

Comment: Well the I don't think that the servlet sending the results in the array format which is accepted by the `autocomplete`. You can chek the response in the `net` tab of your browser console for the foormat that the servlet is returning. It is returning `string` not the array. You have to split the string in array in javascript when you recieve the response, before using it.

Comment: The response doesn't appear on the `net` tab. But I guess trying to pass the data somehow as an array should work, so next step should be figuring that out. Thanks.

Comment: Refer these posts [1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery/) [2](http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/)

Comment: I was using **1** but only got me this far; I'm pretty sure it's outdated. **2** seems outdated too but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

i will show my code for the autcomplete using jQuery UI pluggin, which i used.

please follow the below code,

```
$("#fileNameInput").autocomplete({
        source : function(request,response){
            var url = "autocomplete?type=FileSearch&time="+new Date(); // some URL mapped to servlet
            $.post(url,
                    {   
                        /*
                            'srcIdX' is the extra data i pass, this is send along with 'term',
                            so at servlet i do request.getParamter('term') 
                            and request.getParamter('sourceid')                     
                        */
                        sourceid : $("#srcIdX").val()   
                    },
                    function(data){ 
                        /*
                            here my data which i get from server (i.e. from servlet in response) is as follows
                            {
                                "data" : [
                                    {
                                        "fileName" : "something",
                                        "fileId" : "something",                                         
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "fileName" : "something",
                                        "fileId" : "something",                                         
                                    },......
                                ]
                            }   
                        */
                        var jsonObj  = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if(jsonObj.data != "null"){
                             response($.map(jsonObj.data,function(obj,i){
                                return {
                                    label : obj.fileName,
                                    value : obj.fileName                                        
                                }
                            }))
                        }                        
                    }
            );
        },
        minLength : 1,
        open: function() {
           $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        select: function(event, ui){                                           
            $("#fileIdX").val(ui.item.value);   // THIS IS SOME INPUT HIDDEN WHICH I USE TO STORE THE 'VALUE' OF SELECTED 'LABEL'           

        } 
    });
```

at server side i can pass the jSon using GSON library,
or simply using a string buffer,

```
PrintWriter out =  response.getWriter();

StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
strb.append("{ \"data\" : [ { \"fileId\" : \"12\", \"fileName\" : \"Rahul_source\" },");
strb.append(" { \"fileId\" : \"13\", \"fileName\" : \"doug_source\" }, ");
strb.append(" { \"fileId\" : \"14\", \"fileName\" : \"sridhar_source\" }, ");
strb.append(" { \"fileId\" : \"15\", \"fileName\" : \"FRT\" }, ");
strb.append(" { \"fileId\" : \"16\", \"fileName\" : \"ASWQ_source\" } ");
strb.append("] } ");    

out.write(strb.toString());
```

trying this simple approach will work